# Select highest value from several columns in a single tuple ORACLE

Tags: oracle, max, multiple-columns

I have an Oracle 11g table wich has a unique ID and several columns with numeric values, it looks like this:

```
ID   COL1   COL2     COL3 ...    COLn
 1    0       15       20         12
 2    4       0        10         0
 3    20      0         3         8
```

I need to know, for each row, the column containing the highest value as well as the column name. In this example, for instance, if I select ID = 1, the result should be:

```
COL3
____
20
```

I have tried to use the GREATEST function, but it just returns the value but not the column name. Another way to do it would be using a CASE statement, but this table has more than 300 columns and the one-by-one comparison would be terrible. I have heard about using the PIVOT feature but I don't know exactly how to apply it. Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: What column name should be displayed for your sample data? The first row's highest value is in `col3`, the third row's value is in `col1`. Your sample data only shows a single row result. What column name should be used for multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT D, COLUMN_NAME, VA_LUE
FROM (
    SELECT D, COLUMN_NAME, VA_LUE,  MAX( VA_LUE ) OVER (partition by D) as Max_Value
    FROM table1
    UNPIVOT(
      va_lue FOR column_name IN ( "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", ........
          ......................., "COLN" )
    )
)
WHERE VA_LUE = MAX_VALUE;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13fd5/1